# asp.net code behind vs ajax load for initial page content

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, pageload

In our development environment, we have fully adopted the use of jQuery for ajax calls to .net web services. However, I think our developers might be taking it too far. For example, on an initial page load, very little is actually rendered on the page. Basically, the page layout and some divs where the data will be loaded are the only things rendered. Then ajax calls are made on document ready to load the page with the data driven content. But, they are even using this method for content that is needed from the very beginning and sometimes not even updated dynamically.

My question is, why not load this content using the tradional _load methods in the code behind of the .net page? I can see where you might not want to do this if it is alot of data. The page appears to load faster if you only load a shell and then go get the data. But in the case of a short list/table of data, why make the user wait for the page to load and then another network call to get the data? This small set of data will most likely take the server no time to render to the html, and the impact on the size of the download would be very small.

Opinions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, this comes down to initial page load times versus efficient delivery of initial content; the true barometer of this is the user's expectations/demands on page load time, if they expect a page to immediately load and expect to see a spinner or popup/toast when things are loading, then you should not fight that.

However, if you are trying to "shape" the user's expectations, then I believe you are correct in raising the issue. I would go as far as to say that you should recommend a demonstration of the two techniques and run them side-by-side and let some non-technical stakeholder (the customer if possible) give their opinion.

It is all about managing expectations.